# SmallDateTime from MS-SQL not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I have a strange problem that when using `PHP` to connect to a `MSSQL` database using `freetds` the query returns no data.

I have two `SQL` queries:

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [TBL_Contact] AS C
LEFT JOIN [TBL_Address] AS A
    ON (C.[ContactID] = A.[ContactID])
;
```

and

```
SELECT TOP 100
    N.[NoteID],
    N.[NoteTypeID],
    N.[IsPrivate],
    CAST(N.[NoteText] AS TEXT) AS [NoteText],
    N.[ManageUserID],
    N.[DisplayDate],
    N.[CreateUserID],
    N.[CreateDateE],
    N.[EditUserID],
    N.[EditDate]
FROM [TBL_Note] AS N
LEFT JOIN [TBL_Contact_Note] AS C
    ON (C.[NoteID] = N.[NoteID])
;
```

When run directly on the `MSSQL` Server they both work as expected and return data.  However when running them via PHP by wrapping them in a `mssql_query()` function call.

```
$result = mssql_query('
   SELECT TOP 100 *
   FROM [TBL_Contact] AS C
    LEFT JOIN [TBL_Address] AS A
        ON (C.[ContactID] = A.[ContactID])
    ;
');

$result1 = mssql_query('
    SELECT TOP 100
        N.[NoteID],
        N.[NoteTypeID],
        N.[IsPrivate],
        CAST(N.[NoteText] AS TEXT) AS [NoteText],
        N.[ManageUserID],
        N.[DisplayDate],
        N.[CreateUserID],
        N.[CreateDateE],
        N.[EditUserID],
        N.[EditDate]
    FROM [TBL_Note] AS N
    LEFT JOIN [TBL_Contact_Note] AS C
        ON (C.[NoteID] = N.[NoteID])
    ;
');
```

Then only the first one returns data.

---

I have experimented by removing fields from the query and have found that it is the `smalldatetime` field `N.[DisplayDate]` that is causing the issue.  When I run the query with that field removed then the `mssql_query()` call works.

Comment: Is there data in the `TBL_NOTE` table? Could you please add some example data to your question and some expected query outputs. Also if you run the queries directly on the MSSQL Server do they work as expected?

Comment: Hiya yes there is data and the query worked fine on the server iteself

Comment: Instead editing your question why dont you post it as answer and accept it, which will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found out what the issue is there is a bug with PHP and the smalldatetime data type

There is a fix for this which involves disabling the mssql.datetimeconvert setting in the php.ini file.

The fix found on the web is to using ini_set to change the setting.

```
ini_set('mssql.datetimeconvert', 0);
```

Comment: If your own answer also fixed your problem you should be able to mark your own answer as accepted after the grace period is over. This then indicates that an answer to the problem was found